# Command for setting DocumentRoot for apache on Debian?

Tags: shell-script, apache-httpd, configuration

So I am developing a simple installation script for a Raspberry based app. It installs the LAMP install, grants some permissions among other things. And part of the process is to change the apache DocumentRoot to point to /home/pi/bticino

Is there a command or set of commands to achieve this? I'd like a command that avoids replacing files. And editing the httpd.conf file is not an option (as there should not be human interaction on my script).

Answer (score 2):

The standard Debian way of doing this is to provide a complete virtual host configuration as a new file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, then enable it using `a2ensite` (and perhaps disable the default using `a2dissite`).

So you'd create say `/etc/apache2/sites-available/bticino.conf` containing

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/pi/bticino
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bticino-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bticino-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

then run

```
a2dissite 000-default
a2ensite bticino
service apache2 reload
```

all as root.